# Two imageviews not showing at the same time

Tags: android

Can someone help me?  The two imageviews are not showing at the same time. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="#790000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/beautyico"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/beauty"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    /> 

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textico"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icotxt"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do. Edit your question adding more details please

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have enough height for both of them, since linear layout's orientation is vertical.

change this

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

into

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```